# How can I delete photos from my iPhone but keep them in iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos, photos.app

I have seen this question on here a few times, but never with a clear answer.

I am using a iPhone 6s with iOS 10.3.3. When I take a picture I want it to be uploaded to my iCloud Photo Library; however I also want to be able to delete that photo from my iPhone while keeping it in iCloud (to free up space for other data).

Is there a way to delete photos from my iPhone’s local storage but not from iCloud Photo Library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple’s solution is to manage your storage for you. Under **Settings** → **Photos & Camera**, select to `Optimize iPhone Storage`.

As long as you have enough local storage, photos will remain on your device. When your iPhone needs the space, high-resolution versions of your photos will be removed from your iPhone; all that is kept then is thumbnails, until you decide to view the photo again.

At that point a device-optimized version of the photo is downloaded from iCloud. A full-resolution version won’t be downloaded until you decide to edit or share the photo.

iCloud Photo Library is a photo-sync service, rather than a backup service, which is why deleting a photo anywhere deletes it everywhere. What you see on your device is what you see in iCloud is what you see on all your devices connected to the service.